# How can I use USB interface to send real time data using Beaglebone

Tags: matlab, usb, real-time, beagleboneblack, adc

My professor ask me to find a way to stream ADC data to PC (or Matlab) using a Beaglebone Black Board (BBB) at 10khz~20kHz or more frequencies over usb.

I know that I can use PRUs to program in real time and I know that USB protocol has isochronous transfer mode to stream data. Or I can use USB-serial to archive it.

So my idea is using PRU to capture ADC data and send it over usb to Matlab.

I found a python Library that captures ADC data using PRU, but I don't know how to adapt it to transfer data to PC.

Link:
https://github.com/pgmmpk/beaglebone_pru_adc

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but matlab has [specific toolboxes that tackle input from usb](http://uk.mathworks.com/solutions/test-measurement/). Maybe this makes life easier?

Comment: How will be sure `BBB` serial clock is `STABLE` ? Os level `CLOCK` definition are `FUZZY` ! Need using `IC`or `MCU` for high-speed +stable serial communication. (I tested `teensy 3.01` at `6Mbps` speed without any error !)

Answer (score 1):

USB standard has the USB CDC device class. It can emulate a COM port (RS 232). 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class

You can implement this on the Beaglebone (Beaglebone as device not as host) and then use standard RS 232 libraries in matlab or C to get the data. On linux you see a USB CDC (ACM) device as `/dev/ttyACMx` or `/dev/ttyUSBx`

According to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/-HBwQdkuzes the Beaglebone has implemented USB CDC (ACM) RS232-over-USB yet. This is the easiest way because you can use the standard RS-232 commands in matlab to get the data.

If you use linux plug in the BBB and run `dmesg` or `lsusb -v` to see the inbuilt USB interfaces of the BBB.

this is a very good overview over USB http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

Comment: The problem is that I want to use a high speed transmission (It is 200kHz 12bits) and I if I use RS232 I will be limited to 115kbps. For now I'm using usb over ethernet.

Comment: over USB RS232 speed is not limited to 115kbps, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190995/virtual-com-port-or-using-raw-endpoints/38192868#38192868

Comment: sorry I forget the answer above, I pressed enter without ctrl and I canno edit it again. Here is my full answer:

running both commands I got:

[link]http://pastebin.com/bAyQ62Mn[\link]
and
[link]http://pastebin.com/ZNbb6RZG[\link]

but I didn't understand what does it means and. How can I use rs232 over usb (or just enable it, whatever) using an python or c on bbb?

Comment: for using RS232 over USB you have to implement a CDC driver on the beaglebone. An example is here http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/120730/html/group___group___u_s_b_class_c_d_c_device.html and here http://www.atmel.com/images/doc6269.pdf i do not know what is pre-installed on the beaglebone so you have to check this for yourself.

Comment: `dmesg` outputs the latest kernel messages, with this you can see if the kernel can access your device etc.`lsusb -v` outputs what the usb host on your computer sees if your bbb is plugged in and so it sees the internal structure of the beaglebones usb interface. For understanding the structure of a usb interface you have to learn more about the usb standard (device id, vendor id, device descriptor, configuration, interface, endpoint, control command, bulk transfer,...), see http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml